# Create and register naming pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am working on a C# based application in which I have a utility interface with an internal back end that creates some objects and registers them internally in the application. 
So the code looks like the following:

```
public interface Utility {
     public SomeObject CreateSomeObject(String id);
}
```

Only the `Utility` interface is visible outside my assembly, the concrete back end class is internal. 
I am really stuck on finding a proper name for the creation methods which should tell the user that the wanted object will be **created** and **registered**.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT** I already thought about naming my methods CreateAndRegisterSomeObject() but some objects have really long names which makes some method names very very long

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there a reason not to just call it `createAndRegister`? Too long, perhaps?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yep, I thought about that but it is too long I think

Comment: What I don't like about `createAndRegister` is that it is two actions in one name... but OTOH your method _has_ two actions. So I guess it is the most intuitive name.

Comment: @GETah: Too long? Understanding what a method does is more important than long names.

Comment: How about CRObject and RGObject ?

Comment: @laptop: Are you serious? can you tell what `utility.CRObject(1)` does without looking at the methods source code or the method comments?

Comment: @laptop I will get fired if I name my methods that way :)

Comment: I thought so it might not be good idea. have you come up any simple verb to represent your two actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really like the idea that your method is doing so much ie both create *and* register, but if it *must* then I would approach it by using generics most likely.

```
public interface IUtility {
    T CreateAndRegister<T>(String id) where T : IIdentifiable, new();
    T CreateAndRegister<T>(ComplexInitInfo somethingElse) where T : ISomethingElseable, new();
}
```

This would allow you to cater for multiple classes that have the same construction pattern without putting verbose plumbing code, ie having to create methods containing the name of every single object you need to create and register. Let the generics do the heavy lifting for you.

Your objects would have to implement some interfaces such as

```
public interface IIdentifiable
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexInitInfo
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}

// this is just an example
public interface ISomethingElseable : IIdentifiable
{
    string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would could implement your Utility class in something along the following lines:

```
public class Utility : IUtility
{
    public T CreateAndRegister<T>(string id) where T : IIdentifiable, new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        result.Id = id;

        // do your registration 

        return result;
    }

    public T CreateAndRegister<T>(ComplexInitInfo somethingElse) where T : ISomethingElseable, new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        result.Id = somethingElse.SomeId;
        result.SomethingElse = somethingElse.SomethingElse;

        // do your registration 

        return result;
    }
}
```

**A different approach**

I would also like to point out the pattern you are trying to use `CreateAndRegister` is a problem already solved slightly differently with [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) frameworks (e.g. [ninject](http://ninject.org/), [unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) amongst others)

They allow you to register and associate a given type to a lifetime that the object has. If you want to register types as singletons for example, the IoC framework can do that for you, then when you Resolve you will get an instance of the type you want respecting the lifetime that it has been configured to. You could want for example, a new instance when every time you resolve the type, or a only a new instance per thread, or to have the same instance always returned when you resolve.

In any case, good luck!

Comment: I prefer this one so far! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this.

Using factory you would have something like this:

```
public Class Factory
{
     public static object CreateAndRegister(string className)
     {
         Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
         Object obj = assem.CreateInstance(className, false);

         //Code for registration          

         return obj;
     }
}
```

In code

```
SomeObj obj = (SomeObj)Factory.CreateAndRegister("SomeObj");
```

Comment: You still need to do `new SomeObj` before you can call CreateAndRegister, which would defeat the purpose of CreateAndRegister

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put method as static.

Comment: Why don't you use factory and System.Reflection to instantiate objects by class name?

Comment: You can't use `public` or `static` inside an interface declaration.

Comment: Had forgotten about that. Changed my answer to a better aproach.

Comment: @RaphaelAyres This involves boxing/unboxing, something I want to avoid

Comment: Boxing and unboxing happens when you try to cast a value type to a reference type. I don't see value types in your code, so I think you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Were you tying to say casting instead of boxing and unboxing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `CreateAndRegister` (as suggested in the comments) is hardly a "long" name. I've probably written longer-named methods just this week. If it's the best description for your method, use it.

But if you want a shorter name, you might think about getting some help from the class name. "Utility" is a noise word, like "Manager" or "Helper"; it adds absolutely no meaning. So `IUtility` is meaningless; you could just as well call it `I` for all the value you get out of the type name.

But if the type was named, say, `IRegistrar`, then suddenly you've got meaningful context even before you start writing the method name. A registrar is something that registers things, and if it's got methods with return values, then you know it's also giving you something back. Now you could name the method something short -- perhaps just `GetXxx`. The fact that it's *creating* something is obvious (it's got to get it from somewhere), and the fact that it's *registering* it is implicit in the type name.

```
public interface IRegistrar {
    Foo GetFoo(string id);
    Bar GetBar(string id);
}

var myFoo = _registrar.GetFoo(id);
```